# git log --graph tabular format

Tags: git, format, git-log

I'm trying to make the output of `git log` tabular. After reading different posts and `git log` manual page, I got to this version:

```
git log --graph --pretty=format:'%<(10,trunc)%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%<(20,trunc)%d%Creset %<(50,trunc)%s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit
```

This is not bad but still has two problems.

**First**, I can't force indentation to the graph itself. The first field I can indent is the hash (`%h`). How can I indent a maximum space for the graph itsefl?

[image]

**Second**, If I tried to indent the relative time field (`%cr`) by writting `%<(15)(%cr)`, I got the text indented but the closing bracket is not included in the indented field. See below picture. How can I indent the whole text including the brackets?

[image]

Comment: What about piping it to a text editor (like sed) to format it as you want it ? Your request looks quite specific.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer for the first point:

I had to replace `%<(10, trunc)%Cred%h` with `%>|(15,trunc)%Cred%h`.

From [git-log manual page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt-emltltNgttruncltruncmtruncem):

> `%>(<N>)`, `%>|(<N>)`: similar to `%<(<N>)`, `%<|(<N>)` respectively, but padding spaces on the left

For the second point I found a work-around. I had to adjust the number of columns to the expected output length. This works fine for my case but it is not generic.

This solved the problem:

[image]